# Debian 8.9 / systemd : Removing crashed disk from boot

Tags: boot, debian, mount, systemd

One of my hard drives just crashed on my home server (IO error), and after shutting it down, I can't boot it again. It gives me `A start job is running for dev-disk-by [...]`, waits for 1m30 and then gives me a `Dependancy failed for /mnt/backup` and throws in the emergency mode.

I tried to use a live USB and edit `/etc/fstab` but it didn't work, I tried to run `update-initramfs -u` after it also, it didn't help either. I cannot run `systemctl daemon-reload` from the live usb because I am in a chroot and systemd does not like it.

I tried `systemctl daemon-reload` inside the emergency shell (after removing the line from `/etc/fstab`, but it did not work either, it still wants to mount it...

I'm stuck here, I have everything on this server (even dhcp and dns) and I can't even reach it anymore...

Edit 2 : Note also that I unplugged the hard drive.

I tried something else, as seen on wiki.archlinux.fr : `systemctl mask mnt-backup.mount` (inside the emergency shell). After typing it, the system boots, but the `/` is in read only mode. I can remount it to read/write though. If I unmask the disk and try to add the `nofail` or `noauto` options, I go back to step one, emergency shell...

Edit 3 : **FIXED**

As suggested by McDonald's, instead of answering my own question here is the solution : The steps I said in my second edit fixed it, but I was commenting/editing away the wrong line the whole time (I was removing a mount point used by many LXCs as a bound mount point), so the boot was failing and the root filesystem was mounted read-only. It's weird however that there were no information about this in the log files... (journalctl/dmesg)